# threejs get material map texture by material name

Tags: three.js

in three.js am using OBJMTLLoder to load my object, day by day am learning new things around it, now i want to learn how to change the Material Diffuse, Specular map,Normal map, Light map and transparency of the materials used on the object.

i can get the materials name by traverse the object, now i want to get the corresponding textures that the material used, so i can use that texture as my new `MeshPhongMaterial's` map,

am using given male02 obj model in the three.js it have

```
01_-_Default1noCulling.JPG
male-02-1noCulling.JPG
orig_02_-_Defaul1noCulling.JPG
```

i need to get this textures by the materials used in the object, i have consoled my object it shows an array named map in it's child, there i can see the images used in the object, but i want to get it by the material name and it's corresponding texture image name

Comment: Can you not save the texture to a variable before applying it to the material?

Comment: ok, when and how we can do it ?? Mr @2pha

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you are using OBJMTLLoder

Comment: yes am using `OBJMTLLoder` what is the problem here??

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit confused as to what you want to do. Do you want to change the textures on the object or get the textures to use on a new object?. The map "array" (object) you will probably find is the Diffuse map and an instance of some sort of Three.js texture. The bump map will be in "bumpmap" etc. If you want to get them by name you will probably have to loop over them all.

Comment: thank you @2pha, i can get the textures used in the object by `scene.traverse(function(object3d){  
   object3d.material && object3d.material.map && console.log(object3d.material.map.image.src);` but i want to get the textures with the material name, so i can modify the textures by the selected material name

Comment: So put this inside a function, check the image src with a if statement and return the map variable if true.

Comment: sorry i can't get you

Comment: can you elaborate it pls??

Comment: if i check `object3d.material.map.image.src` with the if(object3d.material.map.image.src) it says material is undefined